# How to change coords of curve in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a curve

```
PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();             
QuadraticBezierSegment pathSeg = new QuadraticBezierSegment(p2,p3,true);
pathFigure.Segments.Add(pathSeg);
pathFigure.StartPoint = p1;
pathFigure.IsClosed = false;
pathGeometry.Figures.Add(pathFigure);
```

How I can change the points of my curve? That's what I've tried:

```
System.Windows.Point a = new System.Windows.Point(p.X, p.Y);
((BezierSegment)s).SetValue(BezierSegment.Point3Property,a);
```

But i get the following exception

> The "System.Windows.Media.BezierSegment" object property can not be set because it is in read only state.*

**The Exception message was translated from polish. Probably not a 100% similar to the original one.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not change coords because my curve was Frozen.
We just need to get **Geometry** correctly.

```
 PathGeometry pathGeometry = (PathGeometry)path.Data;
```

Not

```
 PathGeometry pathGeometry = path.Data.GetOutlinedPathGeometry();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your path or geometry or something else is frozen. You can't change frozen objects. Find and omit `.Freeze()`, then it should work.

#### From MSDN:

> A Freezable is a special type of object that has two states: unfrozen
> and frozen. When unfrozen, a Freezable appears to behave like any
> other object. When frozen, a Freezable can no longer be modified.
>
> A Freezable provides a Changed event to notify observers of any
> modifications to the object. Freezing a Freezable can improve its
> performance, because it no longer needs to spend resources on change
> notifications. A frozen Freezable can also be shared across threads,
> while an unfrozen Freezable cannot.
>
> ...
>
> Once frozen, a Freezable can never be modified or unfrozen; however,
> you can create an unfrozen clone using the *Clone* or *CloneCurrentValue*
> method.
>
> A Freezable can't be frozen if any of the following are true:
>
> •It has animated or data bound properties.
>
> •It has properties set by a dynamic resource. (See the XAML Resources
> for more information about dynamic resources.)
>
> •It contains Freezable sub-objects that can't be frozen.

Comment: @Vova Dowhanych: Have you found out which object(s) was(were) frozen?

Comment: Yes, they frozen, but I don\`t freeze them before, and don\`t know how to unfreeze.

Comment: You can not unfreeze, you can only make a copy from it, if I'm not mistaken. They must be frozen at some level, by default the objects are not frozen. I have not your code. I hope I could help you by question you have asked.

Comment: I need to make some **curve** on **Canvas** with **corners**. When we drug **corner** we need drag **curve** or transform if we click **shift**. So then i need recreate curve all time when mouse move?