# 'System.Windows.Media.PointCollection' must have IsFrozen set to false to modify

Tags: .net, wpf, clone, transformation, rotatetransform

Additional information: Specified value of type 'System.Windows.Media.PointCollection'
must have IsFrozen set to false to modify.

I have path which i resize dynamically.It works fine when i resize it without any rotation.
But once i rotate this path using RotateTransform and then when i
try to resize. Then it gives the error i mentioned above.
The code which is called for changed point is the setter of this Moving class below:

```
public Moving(PolyLineSegment poly, int index, Vector offset) {
    PointCollection ps = poly.Points;
    // ps.IsFrozen = false;  //I tried to do this but i cannot make it true;
    getter = () => new Point(ps[index].X + offset.X, ps[index].Y + offset.Y);;
    setter = (p) => //This is called with new points update
        {
            PointCollection ps1 = ps.Clone(); //I tried to clone but still out of luck,
            Point pt = new Point(ps1[index].X, ps1[index].Y);
            pt.X = p.X - offset.X;
            pt.Y = p.Y - offset.Y;
            ps[index] = pt; //Here i assign new points, IT gives exception at this line
            //ps[index] = new Point(p.X - offset.X, p.Y - offset.Y);
        };
}
```

The code works fine when Path is not rotated but gives exception when   rotated. Please see the code for rotation below:

```
Path path = (System.Windows.Shapes.Path)ElementBeingRotated;
rotateTrans = new RotateTransform();
rotateTrans.Angle = 90;
rotateTrans.CenterX = path.ActualWidth / 2;
rotateTrans.CenterY = path.ActualHeight / 2;
PathGeometry geometry = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(path.Data);
PathGeometry clonedGeo = geometry.Clone();
clonedGeo.Transform = rotateTrans; // applying some transform to it
result = clonedGeo.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
path.Data = result;
```

How to resize path after RotateTransform and why it do not resize after rotation?

Comment: Two notes. 1. Your code would be far better readable if you would assign `ElementBeingRotated as System.Windows.Shapes.Path` to a local variable once and then use that variable instead of the expression. You're even also using `(System.Windows.Shapes.Path)ElementBeingRotated` 2. There is no sense in setting `RenderTransformOrigin` when you do not also set `RenderTransform`.

Comment: If you're not checking for null, better use the explicit cast instead of the as operator here. You would correctly get an InvalidCastOperation if ElementBeingRotated is not a Path, instead of a wrong NullReferenceException.

Comment: Have you tried `path.Data = result.Clone();`?

Comment: Take a look to my answer, there is a usefull information about freezable objects. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43590830/7713750 is ElementBeingRotated frozen?

Comment: @Clemens yes it worked :) path.Data = result.Clone().. Big thanks

Comment: You may probably also drop `clonedGeo` and assign the RotateTransform directly to the Geometry returned from PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry.

Comment: @Clemens its noted.